# Python argparse required arguments from configuration file / dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have number of configuration named arguments for my script. I want to provide them from configuration file and/or command line.

- Some arguments are required / mandatory
- By default these are read from configuration file
- Optionally override them with values from command line
- Must report error when argument is not provided (configuration file or command line)

Have been using set_defaults() before, but this raises error when using `add_arguments(..., required=True)`.

Is there better and working solution for Python 2.7?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

# this dict will be read from configuration file
config_args = {'my_argument': 'value from configuration file'}

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--my-argument', dest='my_argument', required=True)

# use values from configuration file by default
parser.set_defaults(**config_args)

# override with command line arguments when provided
args = parser.parse_args({})
```

This example will cause error:

```
usage: [-h] --required REQUIRED
: error: argument --required is required
```

Comment: `required=True` doesn't make much sense with a default value since it will always have a value.

Comment: you can add default value to each argument like `parser.add_argument('--required', default="test")`

Comment: Here using `default="some value"` does not work, because need to provide it from separate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @hpaulj answer, made slight adjustment for the code. Using ArgumentParser to notify about missing arguments whether provided from command line or config file.

Python27 ArgumentParser does not provide public API for accessing added argument actions. But there is private property `_actions`. So simply looping over `parser._actions` and resetting `required` property if provided from config file is sufficient solution for my use case.

Here is the fixed code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

# this dict will be read from configuration file
config_args = {'my_argument': 'value from configuration file'}

parser = ArgumentParser()
arg = parser.add_argument('--my-argument', required=True)

# use values from configuration file by default
parser.set_defaults(**config_args)

# Reset `required` attribute when provided from config file
for action in parser._actions:
    if action.dest in config_args:
        action.required = False

# override with command line arguments when provided
args = parser.parse_args({})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [355]: config_args = {'my_argument': 'value from configuration file'}
In [356]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

`add_argument` creates and returns an `Action` object.  Let's save a reference to that object, and look at it:

```
In [357]: a1 = parser.add_argument('--my-argument', dest='my_argument', required
     ...: =True)
In [358]: a1
Out[358]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--my-argument'], dest='my_argument', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Notice that its `default` is `None`, the default default for `store`.  Also `required` is set to `True`.

`set_defaults` changes the `a1.default` value:

```
In [359]: parser.set_defaults(**config_args)
In [360]: a1
Out[360]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--my-argument'], dest='my_argument', nargs=None, const=None, default='value from configuration file', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

`set_defaults` can also be used to set a value for a `dest` that doesn't appear in the arguments (illustrated in the docs for subparsers).

Run without arguments, we get an error - because the action is required.  The presence of a default does not override that.

```
In [361]: parser.parse_args([])
usage: ipython3 [-h] --my-argument MY_ARGUMENT
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: --my-argument
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

If we change the `required` attribute to `False` (`a1` is an object whose attributes can, within limits, be changed.  That includes `a1.default`).

```
In [362]: a1.required
Out[362]: True
In [363]: a1.required=False
In [364]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[364]: Namespace(my_argument='value from configuration file')
```

Your config value now appears.  Commandline values can overwrite it.

You can also provide defaults in a `namespace` parameter:

```
In [365]: ns = argparse.Namespace(my_argument='foo')
In [366]: parser.parse_args([], namespace=ns)
Out[366]: Namespace(my_argument='foo')
```

This `foo` value has priority, so the action default or `set_defaults` value isn't used.

https://bugs.python.org/issue29670 `argparse: does not respect required args pre-populated into namespace`

In this bug/issue the user wanted the presence of a value in `ns` to override the `required` test.  That is, he want this `ns` to act as though the value had been provided on the commandline.  My conclusion is that it isn't any easy thing to change.  The current `parse_args` structure does not let us modify or bypass test for things like `required`.

If you want fancier testing, I'd suggest leaving the `default=None`, and do your own testing after parsing.

```
if args.my_argument is None:
    args.my_argument = 'default from config'
```

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj for the in-depth answer! This was enough for me to find a generic solution. Added the answer to my own question.